# Default colored spacing between JPanel and Frame

Tags: java, string, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I wrote a simple program to change the background color randomly while printing "Happy Birthday!" to the screen, but I am seeing a spacing that is unwanted. How can I fix this?

[image: Birthday Program]

Birthday.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Birthday {

    DrawString panel = new DrawString();

    public Birthday() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel);
        f.setTitle("Happy Birthday!");
        f.setLocation(10, 10);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.pack();

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Birthday();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DrawString.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawString extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int x = 350;
        int y = 250;
        int red   = random(0,255);
        int green = random(0,255);
        int blue  = random(0,255);
        Color black = new Color(0,0,0);

        Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
        g.setColor(newColor);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,500);
        g.setColor(black);
        g.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD,40));
        g.drawString("Happy Birthday!",x,y);
    }

    public static int random(int min, int max)
    {
        int range = max - min + 1;
        int number = (int) (range * Math.random() + min);
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with the differences between a resizable and non-resizable frame border.

Because you've called `setVisible` before calling `setResizable`, the window hasn't reacted to to the change in frame decorations...

Try calling `setVisible` last, for example...

```
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
```

This is generally good advice for general UI creation, call `setVisible` last after you've established the UI content and properties ;)

Comment: Calling `f.pack()` in the end of the constructor also worked.

Comment: @HugoSousa Yep, but they've already called `pack` once...might as well  make use of the fact ;)

Comment: Also, `f.add(panel);` should really be `f.setContentPane(panel);`, but this does not address the extra space issue. Just a recommendation.

Comment: I mean removing from where it is and put right in the end of the constructor. It works, but I don't know why (explain me if you know). There's only the timer definition before that (relatively to where it is originally) so I don't see why it works that way.

Comment: @HugoSousa No idea, maybe by that time the frame has being realised enough to recognise the difference in frame border...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I'd says that's more of personal preference (IMHO) as the OP "may" want to add more content to the content.  It's good to know different approaches though